# Django Piston Content Type Always Null

Tags: python, django, django-piston

I had django-piston working a week ago but recently I'm unable to call any web services. Below is a simple example. I have a 'test' service that returns 'yes' if there is a content type and 'no' if content type is null. I've done this because I get HTTP 500 errors when I do a POST and try to parse my parameters via 'data = request.data'. I'm assuming I can't do request.data because the content type is null?

So, here is my simple web service:

```
class testHandler(BaseHandler):
     def create(self, request):
         if request.content_type:
              return 'yes'
         else:
              data = request.data
              return 'no'
```

And here is the urls.py file:

```
class CsrfExemptResource( Resource ):
     def __init__( self, handler, authentication = None ):
         super( CsrfExemptResource, self ).__init__( handler, authentication )
         self.csrf_exempt = getattr( self.handler, 'csrf_exempt', True )

controller_handler = CsrfExemptResource(controllerHandler)
test_handler = CsrfExemptResource(testHandler)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^controller/', controller_handler),
     url(r'^test/', test_handler),
)
```

And finally the code I run from my python terminal to call the service:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'value':'someValue'}) 
req = urllib2.Request("http://127.0.0.1/cindy/api/test/", params) 
result = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

So 'result' always return no, and if I put the line 'request.data' in the service I get a HTTP 500 error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a `data` attribute in the [HttpRequest](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) object.  You might be looking for [`raw_post_data`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#attributes).

Comment: Ok your suggestion lead me down the right track. To get the data I POST I need to do this: myVlaue = request.POST['value']. TY